# Making moving 2D object in Qt OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qkeyevent

I write a deathmatch multiplayer "tanks" game where players can join to server and run a Tank, shoot etc. At the moment I want to make the mechanism of movement around the map (2D). I've tried some methods but they are not satisfying.

Right now I'm using `QTimer` which works perfectly with one player on map, but when I join second they both start to lag.

**keyPressEvent** method

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    switch(event->key())
    {
        case Qt::Key_Up:
            keyUp = true;
            break;
        case Qt::Key_Down:
            keyDown = true;
            break;
    }
 }
```

`keyPressEvent` and `keyReleaseEvent` are similar instead of in release event there is f.e. `keyUp = false` statement.

**movePlayer** method

```
void MainWindow::movePlayer()
{
    if(keyUp)
        ui->widget->playerList[playerID]->move(0.2);
    else if(keyDown)
        ui->widget->playerList[playerID]->move(-0.1);
    if(keyLeft)
        ui->widget->playerList[playerID]->rotate(-5);
    else if(keyRight)
        ui->widget->playerList[playerID]->rotate(5);
    if(keyE)
        ui->widget->playerList[playerID]->rotateCannon(-3);
    else if(keyQ)
        ui->widget->playerList[playerID]->rotateCannon(3);
}
```

**onTimer** method (sends a message to the server with a location of tank)

```
void MainWindow::onTimer()
{
    movePlayer();
    QTextStream out(socket);
    out << QString::number(ui->widget->playerList[playerID]->id)
           + " " + QString::number(ui->widget->playerList[playerID]->getXPos())
           + " " + QString::number(ui->widget->playerList[playerID]->getYPos())
           + " " + QString::number(ui->widget->playerList[playerID]->getRotation()) << endl;
    ui->widget->updateGL();
}
```

How can I write/rewrite code to achieve my goal of running 2 and more tanks smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

*one render, one update*

The problem might be that you handle players independently.

The simple game loop should handle every part in one go. You would prefer to have logic code on one timer and the rendering might be on the other. Or just go with one timer and do all at once every timer step. This should smooth out the gameplay.

```
// pseudo code
clockTick() {
  // do logic
  for (player : players)
    movePlayer(player);
  // Update graphics
  updateGL();
}
```

Be sure to check [this](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html) fantastic article on The Game Loop.

Comment: Thanks. You may wish to amend the return value of the function.

Comment: I could get it in single player game where all logic happens on one computer. But I have no idea how to achieve that with `QTcpSocket`.

Because I'm updating all players in infoReceived() slot which triggers everytime I get info from server.